# PHP mysql_num_rows() usage on INNER JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, mysql-num-rows

```
<?php

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  table_one INNER JOIN table_two ON table_one.id = table_two.field_id ORDER BY table_one.id ASC LIMIT 0 , 300");
$rowCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($rowCount < 1 || $rowCount=="0" || $rowCount == 0 || $rowCount == NULL || $rowCount == false){
        echo "no information retrieved"; 
    }
    else{
        echo "information retrieved";
    }
}

?>
```

So when setting the condition in the if-else statement I tried several ways to catch the $rowCount value of 0 but it just doesn't seem to work for me.

Does my query need to be using syntax that eliminates null joins or how do I identify when $rowCount = 0 ?

Comment: If your query doesn't find any record, it returns 0. All the other conditions are not necessary. Put if clause outside while loop and loop result in the else part if you need to display the results.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't seeing the flow of information properly in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop `while(false) { }` will never execute, and that's what you have when there are no rows. You have to put the check for `$row_count` outside the while-loop:

```
if ($row_count == 0) { ... no information ... }

else
{
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand why my original code doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0):

If your Statement has nothing returned, the `while` loop will never be entered.
The expression `$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)` will evaluate to true only if there was a row fetched.